# Sending image in email body, Android as client side and Asp.net c# as server side

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, server-side

I am developing an android application, in which I have to send an image of the user

In email body. I am sending image data in form of byte array  to server side

from my android code. I don't have much knowledge in asp.net nor C#,

So can anybody please tell me how should I do this?

Although I managed code for sending text in the email body, here is the code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
     try
        {

             var c = HttpContext.Current;
              var emailID = c.Request["emailID"];
              var passwordToSend = c.Request["password"];
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpserver", portno);
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("########", "########");

            MailMessage messageBody = new MailMessage("#########", emailID);
            messageBody.Subject = "FORGOTTEN PASSWORD";
            messageBody.Body = passwordToSend;
            messageBody.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(messageBody);
            Response.Write("$success$");
           // return "true";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Response.Write("$fail$");
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but I am not able to understand how to send the image in the email body, on page load event.

Please, provide code for server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use cid to link resources.

```
static void SendMailWithEmbededImages()
{
//create the mail message
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//set the addresses
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

//set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email";

//first we create the Plain Text part
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");

//then we create the Html part
//to embed images, we need to use the prefix 'cid' in the img src value
//the cid value will map to the Content-Id of a Linked resource.
//thus <img src='cid:companylogo'> will map to a LinkedResource with a ContentId of 'companylogo'
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");

//create the LinkedResource (embedded image)
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource( "c:\\temp\\logo.gif" );
logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
//add the LinkedResource to the appropriate view
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

//add the views
mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


//send the message
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1"); //specify the mail server address
smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: hi @Vishal thanks for answer , but i have to send image data from my android code , i am trying to send image data  as byte array . but in your code i will have to give static path of image . have you got my problem ?

Comment: So, basically you want to upload an image to server. If yes then use following link for implementation: [link] (http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
                   string outputFile="image path";
                   MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(outputFile,  MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                    ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                    disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(outputFile);
                    disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(outputFile);
                    disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(outputFile);
                    disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(outputFile);
                    disposition.Size = new FileInfo(outputFile).Length;
                    disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    smtp.Send(message);
```